# spring Integration kafka outboundchannel object Injection Error by glassfish

Tags: jersey, spring-integration, apache-kafka, glassfish-4, hk2

Added @ImportResource("classpath:outbound-kafka-integration.xml") on top of my SpringConfig class where i create beans in Java code...

Added below dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

it gives the below error  when im debugging from SOAP UI client(my application is rest api)...

```
   MultiException stack 1 of 4
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ConversionService,parent=AbstractExceptionMapper,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,780303454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.<init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:689)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:946)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:981)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1056)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1047)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:600)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 2 of 4
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.xxxxx.apiappwebutils.web.exception.mapper.ValidationExceptionMapper errors were found
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:246)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.<init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:689)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:946)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:981)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1056)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1047)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:600)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 3 of 4
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.xxxx.apiappwebutils.web.exception.mapper.ValidationExceptionMapper
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:386)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.<init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:689)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:946)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:981)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1056)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1047)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:600)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
MultiException stack 4 of 4
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:386)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:689)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:946)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:981)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1056)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1047)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:600)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:837)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mar 01, 2016 10:37:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet jerseyServlet
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ConversionService,parent=AbstractExceptionMapper,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,780303454)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:211)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:234)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)
```

And below is the response from SOAP UI client

```
 <html>

   <head>

      <meta content="HTML Tidy for Java (vers. 26 Sep 2004), see www.w3.org" name="generator"/>

      <title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.28 - Error report</title>

      <style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}.line {height: 1px; background-color: #525D76; border: none;}</style>

   </head>

   <body>

      <h1>HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet jerseyServlet threw exception</h1>

      <p>

         <b>type</b>

         Exception report

      </p>

      <p>

         <b>message</b>

         <u>Servlet.init() for servlet jerseyServlet threw exception</u>

      </p>

      <p>

         <b>description</b>

         <u>The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u>

      </p>

      <p>

         <b>exception</b>

      </p>

      <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet jerseyServlet threw exception

        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)

        org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:262)

        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)

        org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)

        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)

        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)

        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)

        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)

        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)

        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)</pre>

      <p>

         <b>root cause</b>

      </p>

      <pre>A MultiException has 4 exceptions.  They are:

1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=ConversionService,parent=AbstractExceptionMapper,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2136387465)

2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.xxxx.engine.apiappwebutils.web.exception.mapper.GenericThrowableMapper errors were found

3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.xxxxx.engine.apiappwebutils.web.exception.mapper.GenericThrowableMapper

4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory



        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:249)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:357)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)

        org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(Cache.java:97)

        java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)

        org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(Cache.java:154)

        org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.Cache.compute(Cache.java:199)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext.findOrCreate(SingletonContext.java:122)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2072)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:114)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:88)

        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ExceptionMapperFactory.&lt;init>(ExceptionMapperFactory.java:181)

        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

        sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

        java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)

        org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1350)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:271)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:365)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:83)

        org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SingletonContext$1.compute(SingletonContext.java:71)
```

**Im not getting this error if i remove @ImportResource("classpath:outbound-kafka-integration.xml")"**  ie if im using spring-integration-kafka xml im getting error...

Comment: First of all what is the question? You have an error and don't want to resolve it yourself? I don't see any Kafka related words in your StackTrace. Shortly: bad question. Please, rephrase the problem, if you really would like to get the help from other people.

Comment: @ArtemBilan actually i have created a bean for outboundmessagechannel ..but while injecting in the application it gives error saying it cannot Inject ..but am able to see the InputtoKakfka channel created in SpringConfig.Java(while debugging) where im using Java code to create bean for channel by importing the kafka integration xml...please lemme know if its  not clear

Comment: M-m-m. No, that's not true by your StackTrace. You should see there something like `no qualified beans for kafkaOutboundChannel property`, but we see `SystemInjecteeImpl`. I don't say already that you have a strange `kafkaMessageChannel` `@Bean` definition...

Comment: that makes sense will check thanks!!

Comment: @ArtemBilan im able to see this error when i add this "@EnableIntegration
@ImportResource("classpath:outbound-kafka-integration.xml")" on top of SpringConfig.Java ....when i remove it works fine...please suggest

Comment: This is what I see when added the mentioned annotations but as you said I'll add the appropriate tags (spring and jersey) instead of spring-integration and Apache-Kafka for this question ..does it make sense??

Comment: @ArtemBilan can you please lemme know if there is any alternative way other than importing the kafka xml..as im not able to fix this issue with this approach

Comment: I don't know Glassfish at all and that Jersey StackTrace doesn't provide for me any clues. Maybe you should take a look into server logs, not that error page for your SOAP request...

Comment: server log is same as the error which can see in the first stacktrace...anyway i have added Jersey support tag as well to this question...i just have to wait any one from that group responds..

Answer (score 0):

The problem source [HK2 injector](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b03) can't find `ConversionService` instance.

> There was **no object available for injection** at SystemInjecteeImpl(**requiredType=ConversionService**,parent=AbstractExceptionMapper,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,2136387465)

You should revise your services definition or/and share more your configuration here.

Comment: I just added spring-integration-Kafka  1.3 release in Pom and placed the outbound-kafka-integration.xml in resources folder and added the annotations (enableintegration and importresource)as mentioned in my question then it starts giving error w/o this the rest api runs normally

Comment: @shiv455 I suppose Jersey tries to process Spring annotations for somehow. Try to change `@Inject` to `@Autowire` for `MessageChannel kafkaOutboundChannel;`

Comment: even before i declare Bean in Springconfig.Java and Inject kafkaOutboundChannel in my rest api resource class...im getting this error when i tried invoking api from SOAP UI